# XCode is not generating provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have added to developer account as with role "Developer", I used the same account in xcode but not able to generate provisioning profiles.[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you created the Identifier in [Apple Developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list) ?

Comment: dont have access to certificates section in developer.apple.com, i can only login to appstoreconnect.apple.com

Comment: You are not the admin of your Apple Developer account? Ask your admin to do it for you.

Comment: samething happened with admin role too

Comment: Impossible. Admin should have access rights to the Identifier section.